# How do I middle-align my header menu items in WordPress

Tags: theme-development, menus, css

I accidentally moved my header menu items ([screenshot](https://s18.postimg.org/tnvj5gz1l/header-menu.png)) to the top. How do I move them back to the middle (default) as shown in the [demo website](https://www.famethemes.com/preview/?theme=OnePress)?

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not a WordPress related question and should be asked on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) instead, but to align your menu items vertically, you have at least 3 options. Assuming your HTML structure is like the following:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">My FIRST ITEM</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">My SECOND ITEM</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**Option 1** Set the line height of your anchor to the same height as it's parent. Let's say your `<nav>` has a height of 75px. You should set the anchors line height to 75px too:

```
.nav a {
    line-height:75px;
}
```

It doesn't have to be `<nav>`. It's parent can be any of these in this case: `<nav>`, `<ul>` or `<li>`.

**Option 2** Give a height to your anchor's parent and then align the anchor vertically:

```
.li {
    height:75px;
}
.li a {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**Option 3** Give your anchor some paddings. Set the padding for it's top and bottom:

```
.nav a {
    padding:25px 0;
}
```

Try to increase/decrease the amount of padding until the anchor is place in the middle of the line.

All of the above will produce the same effect. However, they might act a bit different in other properties like background's color.